# How can I make an HTML page that edits variables in a .JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Basically I have a .json file, and I want to make a html page that someone can fill out a form, and the information in the form will change variables in the JSON file.

Example:

The json file (for example):

{“title”: “(variable)”}

then when the html form is submitted it will read (variable) as what was entered into the form.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you have on the backend (Node, python, etc)

Comment: i am using Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, seeing that you have NodeJS, you may want to establish some sort of communication from your back end to front end. Let's say you're using websockets. Here is how information would be passed:

userData.json:

```
{
  name: "Mishra",
  age: 89
}
```

server.js:

```
const app = express()
const server = app.listen(3000) // setup express server
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // using websockets
let userData = require('./userData.json');

// on socket connection event
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  
  socket.on('updateName', name => { // when updateName is called
    userData.name = name            // set JSON var to new name
  })

}

// method to save JSON file goes here
```

myForm.html:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="your/path/to/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    Set name:
    <input type="text" id="nameField" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">

    <script>
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = () =>{
            socket.emit("updateName", document.getElementById("nameField").value)
    }
    </script>
</body>
```